# Possible to create plain WASM module with .NET 8

Tags: c#, .net-core, webassembly

I would like to write some of my application logic in C# and be able to update (sideload) it after deploying the host application. Since WASM support has further improved with .NET 8, I considered to package up my application code into a WASM module and execute it securely in a WASM sandbox.
I specifically *don't* require WASI support which could introduce security issues.

Is that at all possible with the current wasm-tools workload or other tooling?

How would I annotate C# functions to be exported from the WASM module?

Is there a minimal working example that replicates e.g. this gct.wat code in C#?
https://docs.wasmtime.dev/examples-c-gcd.html

I tried to use the `wasmconsole` and `wasmbrowser` project templates but both of them yield `.wasm` modules that have dependencies on additional external functions from either the browser or wasi interfaces.

Comment: Most standart tool for converting wasm was 'wasm-tools', you can use with `dotnet workload install wasm-tools` and your project will convert to an wasm project.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I intended using Wasi.Sdk and the WasiLib example from here: https://github.com/zxyao145/csharp-wasi-sdk-demo and this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/46344. Not sure if a more straightforward way exists.

Answer (score 1):

Its experimental, but https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/blob/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM/docs/using-nativeaot/compiling.md#webassembly will build plain wasm modules.  To export functions, use `UnmanagedCallersOnly` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising! I tried to run the resulting wasm module using wasmtime (from C#, see https://docs.wasmtime.dev/lang-dotnet.html) and got the following exception:
`Unhandled exception. Wasmtime.WasmtimeException: WebAssembly module 'wasmmodule' is not valid: invalid section code: 13 (at offset 13346)
   at Wasmtime.Module..ctor(EngineHandle engine, String name, Byte[] bytes)
   at Wasmtime.Module.FromBytes(Engine engine, String name, Byte[] bytes)
   at Wasmtime.Module.FromFile(Engine engine, String path)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args)`